# What category do these products live in?

Tags: category-theory

There is an example at the beginning of Section 7.4 of Awodey's *Category Theory*, where natural transformations are first introduced, and I'm trying to figure out how it relates to the definition of a natural transformation. To give an intuitive feel for the notion, the author refers to functors $F:\mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{D}$ as "constructions" with the intention of showing what a relation between them would look like.

> To give a simple
> example, suppose C has products and consider, for objects $A, B, C \in \mathbf{C}$,
> $$
> (A \times B) \times C \text{ and } A \times (B \times C).
> $$
> Regardless of what objects $A$, $B$, and $C$ are, we have an isomorphism
> $$
> h : (A \times B) \times C \xrightarrow{\sim} A × (B × C).
> $$
> What does it mean that this isomorphism doesn’t really depend on the particular objects $A, B, C$? One way to explain it is this:
> Given any $f : A \to A′$, we get a commutative square
> $$
> \begin{array}{ccc}
> (A \times B) \times C & \xrightarrow{h_A} & A \times (B \times C) \\
> \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
> (A' \times B) \times C & \xrightarrow{h_{A'}} & A' \times (B \times C)
> \end{array}
> $$
> So what we really have is an isomorphism between the “constructions”,
> $$
> (− \times B) \times C \text{ and } − \times (B \times C)
> $$
> without regard to what’s in the argument-place of these.
> Now, by a “construction” we of course just mean a functor, and by a
> “relation between constructors” we mean a morphism of functors (which is
> what we are about to define). In the example, it’s an isomorphism:
> $$
> (− \times B) \times C \cong − \times (B \times C)
> $$
> For functors $\mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}$.

What is the category $\mathbf{D}$ in this example? What's the explicit definition of the functors $F, G$? I'm thinking something bringing us to a space of products of objects in $\mathbf{C}$, but I'm not sure what exactly that would look like. We define natural transformations as having *components* for each object $C \in \mathbf{C}$. What is $C$ in the example? Is it just $A$?

Comment: I think the author is being rather explicit about the fact that they are talking about functors $\mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{C}$, so $\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{C}$. Here $F(A)=(A\times B)\times C$ and $G(A)=A\times (B\times C)$.

Comment: Ah thank you! Yes I think you're right. For some reason I didn't think the products could be in the same category.

Comment: @CaptainLama Do you think you could make this an answer so I could mark it as accepted?

Comment: For anyone who encountered similar difficulties, my confusion stemmed from not understanding the definition of a product. I was under the mistaken impression that a product is an object of the product category, but this is not the case. Products of objects in **C** live in **C**; _ordered pairs_ of objects in **C** live in $\mathbf{C} \times \mathbf{C}$.

Comment: I wrote an answer with some additional explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of two objects of a category $\mathbf{C}$ (when it exists) is another object of $\mathbf{C}$: the product of two sets is a set, the product of two groups is a group, etc.

When the product of two objects exists for any pair of objects, this defines a bifunctor: a functor $\mathbf{C}\times \mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{C}$, sending a pair $(A,B)$ of objects to the product $A\times B\in \mathbf{C}$.

A bifunctor is similar to a bilinear map in linear algebra: just like a bilinear map $f:V\times V\to V$ is such that $f(x,-)$ and $f(-,y)$ are linear functions $V\to V$ when we fiw some $x$ or $y$, a bifunctor $F:\mathbf{C}\times \mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{C}$ defines a functor $F(-,B)$ and a functor $F(A,-)$. In other words, the product is a functor if you fix one of the terms.

Here the author is talking about the functors $\mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{C}$ defined by $A\mapsto (A\times B)\times C$ and $A\mapsto A\times (B\times C)$ (which turn out to be naturally isomorphic by some form of associativity of products).